# Huawei Ascend P7 locks out after months of usage

Tags: locked-out, huawei, huawei-ascend-p7

I have been using my Huawei Ascend P7 for months. It was acquired unlocked, I've been using the same SIM card from a prepaid carrier since the very beginning.

Today, without any action taken on my side, no application installed, OS not upgraded recently, the phone locked.

The device prompts me to enter a code, with the following message:

> Please unlock your phone first

I've been looking it up online and stumbled upon some websites that offer release codes for money (or other dubious favors), but it just doesn't make any sense:

- The device was never rooted
- I haven't upgraded my OS lately
- It's not about a SIM card lock
- I talked to my carrier, they haven't been able to help
- The phone worked for **months**, unlocked, exactly the way it was purchased from an authorized Huawei seller in Germany

Does anybody have any idea what could cause this? What could possibly lock an originally unlocked device without any action by the user?

I should note that I don't wish to root my P7.

Comment: Have you contacted Huawei support?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't a hard-lock on the device, it was just a code that apparently I set when I started the phone for the very first time. Sorry for alarming whoever spent time pondering with me about this issue!